# How can I access a linked resource in my assets directory?

Tags: android, eclipse, assets

I have an external folder being referenced in my android project. It is located inside my assets folder. I have files inside this linked resource that I wish to access. However, when I tried to access any of these files, I got a `NullPointerException`.

I attempted to simply print a list of all files in the assets folder, but the linked resource is not included.

the directory looks similar to this:

```
assets >
- folder_1 >
- - file_1
- folder_2 >
- - file_2
- linked_folder >
- - file linked_file
- folder_3 >
```

and the code `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ctx.getAssets().list("")));` prints out the list `[folder_1, folder_2, folder_3]`. Note that this doesn't include the linked folder.

So, how can I link my android project to an external resource and be able to access those files?

Comment: what do you mean by linked folder/resources?

Comment: The linked folder is a reference to an external folder. Instructions here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm

Comment: You want to apply a feature in the Eclipse IDE to an Android app. That is not possible. Eclipse is speaking about a resource for the IDE. Not about resources for an Android app. It simply will not be packed with the app as you have seen already.